# How to get a Collada model to rotate around its own centre axis, when the model is imported into iBooks Author

Tags: 3d-view, axis, transform-orientation

So I export complex models from Blender into collada format and then import them into iBooks Author.

As the images show, the object doesn't rotate around its own centre of axis, it chooses something random, and thus the model doesn't rotate correctly around its centre in iBooks.

Is there some setting I can use while exporting it into the collada format, or is there something I could do to the model to get it to rotate correctly. I have tried joining all the objects into one and then changing its origin to the geometry, but that doesn't work.

Any ideas ?[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure that after you joined and set the object 's origin to geometry it is placed at 0, 0, 0 location in Blender before exporting. Other than that it's hard to tell how that application decides what rotation point to use if not origin point.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work

Comment: I think it takes the bounds centre of the object and not the median centre. I tried changing the origin point in blender to median centre but iBooks still uses the bounds centre and not the median centre.